# Find pattern to solve regex in one step

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem to find the pattern that solves the problem in onestep.
The string looks like this:

```
Text1
Text1$Text2$Text3
Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6 etc.
```

What i want to get is: Take up to 4x Text. If there are more than "4xText" take only the last sign.

Example:

```
Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6 -> Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4&56
```

My current solution is:

First pattern:

```
^([^\$]*)\$?([^\$]*)\$?([^\$]*)\$?([^\$]*)\$?
```

After this i will do a substitution with the first pattern
New string: `Text5$Text6`

second pattern is:

```
([^\$])\b
```

result: 56

combine both and get the result:

```
Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$56
```

For me it is not clear why i cant easily put the second pattern after the first pattern into one pattern. Is there something like an anchor that tells the engine to start the pattern from here like it would do if is would be the only pattern ?

Comment: Dear Abra, i use C#

Comment: Regular expressions only allow for selection of contiguous text. Your host language may offer a way to extract substrings by way of capturing parentheses etc.

Comment: Is regex actually a requirement ? There are plenty of simple way to do that

Comment: ok thanks, So my solution is not so wrong? No Regex would not be a requirement. But i like it. What would you prefer ?

Comment: using C#, il would bet on a simple *split on $* then take the 4 first, then take the remaining, ...

Answer (score 3):

You might use an alternation  with a positive lookbehind and then concatenate the matches.

```
(?<=^(?:[^$]+\$){0,3})[^$]+\$?|[^$](?=\$|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^(?:[^$]+\$){0,3}` Match 0-3 times any char except `$` followed by an optional `$`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[^$]+\$?` Match 1+ times any char except `$`, then match an optional `$`
- `|` Or
- `[^$]` Match any char except `$`
- `(?=\$|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is either `$` or the end of the string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%24%5d%2b%5c%24%29%7b0%2c3%7d%29%5b%5e%24%5d*%5c%24%3f%7c%5b%5e%24%5d%28%3f%3d%5c%24%7c%24%29&i=Text1%0d%0aText1%24Text2%24Text3%0d%0aText1%24Text2%24Text3%24Text4%24Text5%24Text6&o=m) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cYf0rl)

Example

```
string pattern = @"(?<=^(?:[^$]*\$){0,3})[^$]*\$?|[^$](?=\$|$)";
string[] strings = { 
    "Text1",
    "Text1$Text2$Text3",
    "Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6"
};            

Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

foreach (String s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", from Match match in regex.Matches(s) select match.Value));
}
```

Output

```
Text1
Text1$Text2$Text3
Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$56
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe regular expression isn't the way to do that. Mostly because of the readability.

You may consider using simple algorithm like this one to reach your goal:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6";
        var parts = input.Split('$');
        
        var result = "";
        for(var i=0; i<parts.Length; i++){
            result += (i <= 4 ? parts[i] + "$" : parts[i].Substring(4));            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

There are also linq alternatives :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6";
        var parts = input.Split('$');
                
        var first4 = parts.Take(4);
        var remainings = parts.Skip(4);
        
        var result2 = string.Join("$", first4) + "$" +  string.Join("", remainings.Select( r=>r.Substring(4)));
        
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}
```

It has to be adjusted to the actual needs but the idea is there

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var texts = new string[] {"Text1", "Text1$Text2$Text3", "Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$Text5$Text6" };

var parsed = texts
     .Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, 
         @"(Text\d{1,3}(?:\$Text\d{1,3}){0,3})((?:\$Text\d{1,3})*)", 
         (match) => match.Groups[1].Value +"$"+ match.Groups[2].Value.Replace("Text", "").Replace("$", "")
     )).ToArray();

// parsed is now: string[3] { "Text1$", "Text1$Text2$Text3$", "Text1$Text2$Text3$Text4$56" }
```

Explanation:

solution uses regex pattern: `(Text\d{1,3}(?:\$Text\d{1,3}){0,3})((?:\$Text\d{1,3})*)`

`(...)` - first capturing group

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`Text\d{1,3}(?:\$Text\d{1,3}` - match `Text` literally, then match `\d{1,3}`, which is 1 up to three digits, `\$` matches `$` literally

Rest is just repetition of it. Basically, first group captures first four pieces, second group captures the rest, if any.

We also use `MatchEvaluator` here which is delegate type defined as:

```
public delegate string MatchEvaluator(Match match);
```

We define such method:

```
(match) => match.Groups[1].Value +"$"+ match.Groups[2].Value.Replace("Text", "").Replace("$", "")
```

We use it to evaluate match, so takee first capturing group and concatenate with second, removing unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether your goal can be achieved using *exclusively* regex. If nothing else, the fact that you want to introduce a new character `'&'` into the output adds to the challenge, since just plain matching would never be able to accomplish that. Possibly using the `Replace()` method? I'm not sure that would work though...using only a replacement pattern and not a `MatchEvaluator`, I don't see a way to recognize but still exclude the `"$Text"` portion from the fifth instance and later.

But, if you are willing to mix regex with a small amount of post-processing, you can definitely do it:

```cs
static readonly Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(Text\d(?:\$Text\d){0,3})(?:\$Text(\d))*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        string text = string.Join("$", Enumerable.Range(1, i).Select(j => $"Text{j}"));

        WriteLine(KeepFour(text));
    }
}

private static string KeepFour(string text)
{
    Match match = regex1.Match(text);

    if (!match.Success)
    {
        return "[NO MATCH]";
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result.Append(match.Groups[1].Value);

    if (match.Groups[2].Captures.Count > 0)
    {
        result.Append("&");
        // Have to iterate (join), because we don't want the whole match,
        // just the captured text.
        result.Append(JoinCaptures(match.Groups[2]));
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

private static string JoinCaptures(Group group)
{
    return string.Join("", group.Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value));
}
```

The above breaks your requirement into three different capture groups in a regex. Then it extracts the captured text, composing the result based on the results.